# How to Serialize Rust Enum as YAML with Variant Name as Key?

Tags: rust, yaml, serde

I'm working with Rust to deserialize YAML data into an enum, but I want to use the key of a map in the YAML file as the tag which identifies the enum variant. Here's the relevant code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum Sink {
    Csv(CsvSink),
    Json(JsonSink),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct CsvSink {
    file_path: String,
    delimiter: char,
    append: bool
}
```

Currently, I can deserialize from this YAML file:

```yaml
!csv
  file_path: "tmp/output-data.csv"
  delimiter: ,
  append: true
```

However, I want the YAML to look like this (i.e.:

```yaml
csv:
  file_path: "tmp/output-data.csv"
  delimiter: ,
  append: true
```

How can I adjust my code to use the key in the yaml as the tag which determines the enum variant?

I have tried using different serde container attributes but have not found the right option

Comment: I can't parse the first YAML with the given structure as-is but I can parse the second YAML (with quotes around `,`) just fine with no structure changes ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3212b82b125e6413ede5031c0947ca28)). So I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @kmdreko Interesting.. This is the exact error I am getting in my dev environment.


```called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("invalid type: map, expected a YAML tag starting with '!'", line: 2, column: 9)```


Is it possible to see which version of serde_yaml is being used in the playground?

Comment: On the playground, if you type `use <crate>` it can autocomplete what crates are available which includes the version. Currently it is 0.8.26.

Comment: @kmdreko I have found that this works if I switch from `serde_yaml` version 0.9.30 (latest) to 0.8.26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[One of the breaking change in `serde_yaml` v0.9.0 is (de)serializing enum variants as `!` tags instead of maps](https://github.com/dtolnay/serde-yaml/releases/tag/0.9.0). The old behavior can be restored with [`serde_yaml::with::singleton_map`](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/0.9.30/serde_yaml/with/singleton_map/index.html), but this requires a wrapper type to apply the `#[serde(with)]` attribute to it:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(transparent)]
pub struct Wrapper(#[serde(with = "serde_yaml::with::singleton_map")] pub Sink);

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum Sink {
    Csv(CsvSink),
    Json(JsonSink),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct CsvSink {
    file_path: String,
    delimiter: char,
    append: bool,
}
```